# Cant seem to find a bug in c program

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I am literally copying code from Programming in C by Stephen G. Kochan, but I took the liberty to make a few changes. Now the output is not what I expected. I spent the last 12 hours over variations of the same code. I wuld appreciate if anyone can help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

            struct entry{
                char word[15];
                char definition[50];
            };

            int compareStrings(char s1[], char s2[]){
            //this seems to have successfully compare strings
                int i = 0;
                int answer;
                while(s1[i] == s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0'){
                    i++;
                    printf("%i\n", i);

                }

                if(s1[i] > s2[i]){
                        answer = 1;
                    }else if(s1[i] < s2[i]){
                        answer = -1;
                    }else{
                        answer = 0;
                }

                return answer;
            }

            int lookup(struct entry dictionary[], char c[], int entries){
             //
                int mid, high, low, result;
                high = entries -1;
                low = 0;

                int compareStrings(char s1[], char s2[]);


                while(low <= high){
                    mid = (high + low) / 2;
                    result = compareStrings(dictionary[mid].word, c);
                    printf("mid ==> %i and result ==> %i\n", mid, result);
                    if(result = 1){
                        high = mid -1;

                    }else if(result = -1){
                        low = mid + 1;
                    }else{
                        return mid;
                    }


                }
                return -1;


            }

            int main(void){


                struct entry  dictionary[100] =
            { { "aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"        },
            { "abyss",    "a bottomless pit"                  },
            { "acumen",   "mentally sharp; keen"              },
            { "addle",    "to become confused"                },
            { "aerie",    "a high nest"                       },
            { "affix",    "to append; attach"                 },
            { "agar",     "a jelly made from seaweed"         },
            { "ahoy",     "a nautical call of greeting"       },
            { "aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers" },
            { "ajar",     "partially opened"                  } };

                char input[10];
                int result;
                int entries = 10;
                int lookup(struct entry dictionary[], char c[], int entries);
                printf("Please provide input for test\n");
                scanf("%s", input);
                result = lookup(dictionary, input, entries);



                printf("result %i\n", result);
                if(result != -1){
                    printf("%s\n", dictionary[result].word);
                }else{
                    printf("Sorry, %s is not a word\n", input);
                }

                return 0;
            }
```

I expect result to be equal to 1 when the input does exist in the dictionary. But it I get -1:

Example output:

```
Please provide input for test
ajar
1
mid ==> 4 and result ==> -1
1
mid ==> 1 and result ==> -1
1
mid ==> 0 and result ==> -1
result -1
Sorry, ajar is not a word
```

Comment: If you are making changes, you are not "literally copying". Confusing.

Comment: 1) `if(result = 1){` --> `if(result == 1){`

Comment: Of topic: `scanf("%s", input);``  is an absolute no-go

Comment: Avoid `scanf()` and look up some examples with `fgets()` and `strtok_r()`. Much safer way to parse.

Comment: You are right, @unwind; I switched up a few things.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I cant believe these I had this assignment and deep equation mixed up here. , thank you very much. I appreciate the swift help!!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yeap, After fixing the equal sign, I works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: this line: `if(result = 1){` is an assignment, not a comparison.  This kind of keypunch error is rather common.  The reason that placing the literal value on the left of the comparison is highly prefered is when something like: `if(1 = result)` is written, the compiler will catch it and output a warning message.  Placing the literal on the left will save you many gray hairs and hours and hours of debug time.